# How to move an element from one div to another using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to move an element from one div to another div.

Lets say for example there is a button in DIV-A and I want to move it in DIV-B.

It can be easily done in jQuery like

```
$("div-b").append('button');
$("div-a button").remove();
```

But I am not able to think where to start with in AngularJs 1x.
There are a series of 10-20 divs in a row and I want to move the button from one div to another sequentially.

Comment: [`angular.element`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element): "Wraps a raw DOM element or HTML string as a jQuery element."

Comment: I think this can be done with angular's jqlite alone.

Answer (score 0):

In angular data are represented as objects

```
<div ng-repeat="a in ctrl.a"></div>
<div ng-repeat="b in ctrl.b"></div>

vm.a = ['a1', 'a2'];
vm.b = [];

function move(obj) {
    // find obj in vm.a and remove
    // push obj in vm.b
}
```

then the view should be updated automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The moveItem function will move all children elements from one div to another.
   All the events and watchers will survive this, the elements still will be in controllers they where before the move, just the other place in DOM.

requires JQuery

```
    var dom = angular.element($window.document);
    var itemFrom = [];
    var itemTo = [];

    var moveItems = function (from, to) {
      from.children().appendTo(to);
    };

    var changeHeader = function () {  

        if (itemFrom.length === 0) {
            itemFrom = dom.querySelectorAll("#itemFrom");
        }
        if (itemTo.length === 0) {
            itemTo = dom.querySelectorAll("#itemTo");
        }

        moveItems(itemFrom, itemTo);
    };
```